# wordpress simple loop, huge issues

Tags: loop

Im having a problem where for some reason, a basic loop im trying to add to a sidebar keeps....keeps looping on interior pages (single and page .php ) but not on index.php.

on index.php (home page) is fine.

for example, i wanted the loop to populate an unordered lists line items, so i went about it like this:

```
      <div id="sideBarMain">
        <h2>title4sidebar</h2>
       <ul>     
             <?php 
            query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'left_sidebar', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby=menu_order' ) );
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();  ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </ul>

      </div><!-- sidebar ender -->
```

A few things are happening. 
1. the MOST problematic is that when this loop is in place, it breaks the navigation and all. i click on a page and the page loads up with one of the list line items on the header...so if i click "about us" on the main nav, a page loads with "line item title" instead.....

also happens on any item clicked.

2 - is that on the (page/single.php pages), on the sidebar, it will post the first 4 posts with the category "left_sidebar" how it should be displayed, css in place and all but after the fourth line item, it will repeat the loops one more time.

3 - My sites content area has 2 columns, the sidebar on the left, and the main content area on the middle. On the part that's being wrongfully repeated (after the loops repeats), when i checked with FireBug, on the repeated line items, its also taking the H tag properties from i assume, an h-tag thats next to it on another column. So the first 4 line-items come out fine with the styles given to them via CSS, link colors, rollovers etc, and the next buggy 4 line items come out un-styled, permalink also isnt being applied to them like the first 4 etc.

3 - i removed all html from that php loop like the divs and ul / lis etc so no css is being applied, this way only text come up from the loop but the same thing happens, Since i removed the html portion of the loop, the first 4 li's come up with the standard default blue link text etc, and the following buggy 4 come up the same as before all big with htags attached....

Troubleshooting it all,
- theres only one loop on the page which stems from the sidebar.
- ive properly cleared all floats
- when checking on W3C for errors etc, there are none. green lights through and through.
- no errors on the php side of things. (ive checked every page and have errors enabled) on local server.

im lost.

Any ideas as to what can be happening?

NOTE: thinking ahead, although there is one loop ONLY on the sidebar.php page, once imported technically theres 2 loops which i guess is the sidebar wp loop, and the page.php / single.php loops which get the content.

is there anything different as of the latest wp maybe? Ive always done it like this and now i have problems......

any ideas? im lost.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Multi-post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14674390, please check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `wp_reset_query();` after your loop to prevent other loops on the page (for example, the navigation) to break.

```
<?php 
    query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'left_sidebar', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby=menu_order' ) );
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>

<li><a href="<?php the_permalink();  ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query(); // reset query
?>
```

Does this also fix your other problems?

reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Usage

Answer (score 8):

**[Don't use `query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Caveats)**

> query_posts() is meant for altering the main loop. It does so by replacing the query used to generate the main loop content. Once you use query_posts(), your post-related global variables and template tags will be altered. Conditional tags that are called after you call query_posts() will also be altered - this may or may not be the intended result.

Despite the Codex telling you it's only for altering the main loop, I would go further and say there's no reason to use `query_posts`, ever. Use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main loop.

For your case, creating additional loops in templates, **use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)**:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'left_sidebar',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby=menu_order'
);

$sidebar_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $sidebar_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $sidebar_query->have_posts() ) :
        $sidebar_query->the_post();
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();  ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: WP_Query is the way to go for sure.

Answer (score 6):

1) Yes, this will break navigation because [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts) **overwrites the main page Loop**. Don't use `query_posts` for secondary Loops-- really I can't think of a good reason to use it ever. Use a new [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object (my preference) or a function like [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

```
$myquery = new WP_Query( 
  array ( 
    'category_name' => 'left_sidebar', 
    'posts_per_page' => 4, 
    'orderby=menu_order' 
  ) 
);
if ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : 
  while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : 
    $myquery->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();  ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li><?php   
  endwhile; 
endif;
```

The other problems may be related but your descriptions are confusing.